# SQL query w/ ISNULL won't output smalldatetime to 101 format

Tags: casting, sql-server-2008-r2, isnull, smalldatetime

Snippet from a SQL query (using SQL Server 2008 R2):

```
, CONVERT (VARCHAR(10), s.ENTER_DATE, 101) "Enrollment Start Date"

, CONVERT (VARCHAR(10), (ISNULL(CAST(s.LEAVE_DATE AS VARCHAR(10)), '')) ,101) "Enrollment Drop Date"
```

The top line works fine to output the date to proper 101 format (eg: `06/22/2012`).

The bottom line works as desired to remove any NULL values to a blank, **but**... for any date values it does not output that date to proper 101 format, instead outputting the date in the default format (eg: Jun 22 2012).

I've played with the code and searched online but I cannot get the desired result.

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second expression evaluates like this:

1. A `date` or `datetime` value is converted to a string (using `CAST()`)
2. `ISNULL()` is applied which returns the same result (the same string) if it is not NULL.
3. The string is converted to... a string (using `CONVERT()` this time).

So, as you can see, you get the wrongly formatted date as a result of the innermost conversion.

You just need to apply `ISNULL` differently, I think. Probably like this:

```
ISNULL(CONVERT (VARCHAR(10), s.ENTER_DATE, 101), '') "Enrollment Start Date"
```

Comment: +1 I'd only suggest `[brackets]` are better for aliases than `"double quotes"` simply because many people confuse those as strings.

Comment: Yes... seeing it now makes much clearer sense.  And IT WORKED - thanks for your time and your clarification!